# How to optimize start time of new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions) - java - selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

My Firefox driver takes around 4 seconds to start each time i run test.
Is it possible to create singleton FirefoxDriver and change its firefoxOptions in runtime ?

Currentcode:

```
public WebDriver getWebdriver() {

    FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = getModifiedFirefoxOptions();
    log.error("fnal opt start");
    FirefoxDriver firefoxDriver =  new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
    log.error("fnal opt end"); // taking minimum 4 seconds each time
    return firefoxDriver;
}
```

Is it possibel to do something like

`firefoxDriver.setOptions(firefoxOptions)` // to save this 4 seconds

I checked but there is not set option in firefoxDriver

Selenium version : 3.14.0

Java - 8